# Controllers CRUD para relaciones polimorficas, Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, controller

encuentro un problema a la hora de realizar el CRUD cuaNo me queda claro la manera de actuar. A continuación pueden observar una imagen con un esquema de las relaciones entre tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es como haría el ImageController, CommentController...  de los Modelos con relaciones polimorficas. a continuación adjunto una serie de Modelos:

-User.php

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

//un usuario tiene muchos videos
public function videos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

//un usuario tiene muchos fotos
public function fotos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

//un usuario tiene muchos comentarios
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}

//un usuario tiene una imagen
public function image()
{
    return $this->morphOne(Image::class, 'imageable');
}
```

-Post.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

//un post pertenece a un categoria
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

//un post tiene muchos comentarios
public function comments()
{
    //especie de hasMany pero polimorfico
    return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
}

//un post tiene una imagen
public function image()
{
    //polimorfismo a uno
    return $this->morphOne(Image::class, 'imageable');
}

//un post puede tener muchas etiquetas
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable');
}
```

-Image.php

```
public function imageable()
{   //transformar a pero no especificamos a que
    return $this->morphTo();
```

-Foto.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

//un video pertenece a un categoria
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

//un video tiene muchos comentarios
public function comments()
{
    //especie de hasMany pero polimorfico
    return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
}

//un video tiene una imagen
public function image()
{
    //polimorfismo a uno
    return $this->morphOne(Image::class, 'imageable');
}

//un video puede tener muchas etiquetas
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable');
}
```

-Comment.php

```
  public function commentable()
{   //transformar a pero no especificamos a que
    return $this->morphTo();
}

//un comentario pertenece a un usuario
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Según esto en  mi PostController.php sería:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    //validacion
    $this->validate($request, ['name'=>'required', ]);

    $post = new Post; 

    $post->category_id=$request->category_id;
    $post->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
    $post->name=$request->name;

    $post->save();

    return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id)->with('info', 'Post creado con exito');

}
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    //
    $user= Auth::user();
    if ($user->id==$post->user_id) {
        return view('posts.edit', compact('post'));
    }
    else{

        return redirect()->route('home')->with('info', 'Solo puedes editar o borrar tus posts');

    }
```

Como haría la function store y create para el modelo Image y Comment?
No se como utilizar en estos casa las function que tienen relaciones polimorficas

Comment: La imagen la subirías junto con el Post o es un formulario aparte?

Comment: La imagen estaría en una tabla distinta al post, y dicha imagen formaria parte del post. La idea es que al hacer el formulario del post me de la opción de subir imagen.

Comment: La tabla imagen, tendría imagenes del post, del video, del usuario... es decir, todas las imagenes que precise la aplicación

Comment: Sería útil que agregues a la pregunta el formulario que usas en la vista para crear el post

Answer (score 0):

Ya que la pregunta es bastante amplia y habría varias maneras de hacerlo, te paso una forma simple para que tengas un punto de partida. Una vez que tengas claro esto, puedes hacer algo mas complejo para no repetir código en cada Controlador de `Posts` y `Videos`, por ejemplo, creando un `Servicio` para guardar la `Image`, los `Comment` y las `Tag`.

**PostController.php**:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // creas el Post como ya lo estabas haciendo
    // ...
    $post->save();

    // chequeas que el usuario haya subido una imagen
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        // obtienes el nombre del archivo
        $filename = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        // lo guardas en el disco 'public'en el directorio 'images'
        $request->file('image')->storeAs('images', $filename, 'public');
        // obtienes la url del archivo que guardaste
        $url = Storage::url('images/'.$filename);
        // creas una instancia del modelo Image con el valor para el campo 'url'
        $image = new Image(['url' => $url]);
        // insertas la Image directamente desde el método de save() de la relación
        $post->image()->save($image);
    }

    return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id)->with('info', 'Post creado con exito');

}
```

Para insertar un `Comment`, te paso una forma de hacerlo en el mismo controlador del `Post`. En el request deberás enviar la id del `Post` (`post_id`) al que pertenece el `Comment` y su `body`:

```
public function storeComment(Request $request)
{
    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->user_id = Auth::id();
    $comment->body = $request->body;

    $post = Post::find($request->post_id);

    $post->comments()->save($comment);

    return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id)->with('info', 'Comentario creado con exito');
}
```

Tendrás que crear una ruta para acceder a este método:

```
Route::post('/posts/comments', 'PostController@storeComment');
```

**Referencias**:
Laravel Eloquent: Relationships [Inserting & Updating Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)
Laravel [File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem)

Comment: Muchas GRACIAS. No se que pasa pero no me guarda la imagen en el disco 'public' en el directorio 'images'. Tengo en filesystems.php                                            'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => publlic_path(),,,,]

Comment: Lo cambie por un tutorial que leí, no sé si es pertinente pero entendi que así podría clasificar imagenes... no obstante ahora eso no me importa. Ahora en la carpeta public tengo la carpeta images y otras css, js y algún archivo. el archivo filesystems.php   'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => publlic_path(),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

Comment: Prueba dejándolo como lo trae laravel https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/7d62f500a789416738a7181d5217d33ca096db04/config/filesystems.php#L51

Comment: Lo he dejado como lo trae laravel pero no puedo ver la imagen en la carpeta images de 'public'.  No puedo ver la imagen en la carpeta 'images' pero cuando pregunto por url me responde  /storage/images/nombre_de_imagen.jpg

Comment: Es que no va a estar en la carpeta images de `/public`. Buscalo en la carpeta `/storage/app/public/images`

Comment: Problema de imagenes resuelto, voy a ponerme con el resto.... Gracias